# Declaração de String

Tags: java, variáveis

Estou declarando uma variável assim:

```
private String[,] soloMarciano;
```

Pode fazer isso no Java? Pois preciso ler duas posições X e Y.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que quer fazer? Qual resultado espera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você esta querendo chama-se matrizes ou vetores bidimensionais, achei neste [link](http://www.devmedia.com.br/matrizes-aprenda-a-trabalhar-com-vetores-bidimensionais-revista-easy-java-magazine-22/25766) uma explicação bem ampla a respeito do funcionamento deles.

Mas resumindo, você pode declarar um array bidimensional 2 por 4 (8 elementos) da seguinte forma:

```
String[][] xy = new String[2][4];
```

Comment: É importante também salientar na sua resposta, que o tamanho do vetor seja definido antes de seu uso, pois seu tamanho não é dinamico como no caso do [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode declarar e inicializar a string de duas dimensões dessa forma dessa forma:

```
private string[][] soloMarciano = {{"a","b"},{"c","d"}};
```

ou declarar e inicializar ela assim:

```
private string[][] soloMarciano;

soloMarciano[0][0] = "a";

soloMarciano[0][1] = "b";

soloMarciano[1][0] = "c";

soloMarciano[1][1] = "d";
```

Para ler a letra "a", você pode usar um `System.out.println([0][0]);`

A letra "b", use `System.out.println([0][1]);`

A letra "c", use `System.out.println([1][0]);`

A letra "d", use `System.out.println([1][1]);`